# Find $\lim_{x\to\infty}x^2 \left( e^{1/x}-e^{1/(x+1)} \right)$ without using the L'Hopital's rule or Taylor's series

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

This limit is proposed to be solved without using the L'Hopital's rule or Taylor series:
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}x^2 \left( e^{1/x}-e^{1/(x+1)} \right).
$$
I know how to calculate this limit using the Taylor expansion:
$$
x^2 \left( e^{1/x}-e^{1/(x+1)} \right)=
x^2 \left( 1+\frac1{x}+\frac1{2!}\frac1{x^2}+\ldots - 1-\frac1{x+1}-\frac1{2!}\frac1{(x+1)^2}+\ldots \right)
$$
$$
=x^2 \left( \frac1{x(x+1)}+\frac1{2!}\frac{2x+1}{x^2(x+1)^2}+\ldots \right)=
\frac 1{1+\frac1{x}}+\frac1{2!}\frac{2x+1}{(x+1)^2}+\ldots,
$$
thus, the limit is equal to $1$.

I'm allowed to use the fact that $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1}{x}=1$, but I don't know how to apply it to this problem.

Comment: Take one exponent out of bracket.

Comment: Both terms in parentheses tend to $1$. And then you can replace them with their logs (justify this).  This simplifies the problem a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}x^2 \left( e^{\frac1x}-e^{\frac{1}{x+1}} \right)=\lim_{x\to\infty}x^2 e^{\frac{1}{x+1}}\left( e^{\frac1x-\frac{1}{x+1}}-1 \right)=\\
=\lim_{x\to\infty}x^2 \left( e^{\frac{1}{x(x+1)}}-1 \right)=\lim_{x\to\infty}x^2\frac{1}{x(x+1)} = 1$$
On last step we use $\lim_\limits{y\to0}\frac{e^y-1}{y}=1$   considering it with composition $y=\frac{1}{x(x+1)}$, knowing $\lim_\limits{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x(x+1)}=0$. Exact conditions for composition/substitution you can find on my answer from [Bringing limits inside functions when limits go to infinity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4545377/bringing-limits-inside-functions-when-limits-go-to-infinity/4545387#4545387)

Comment: Where does the last step come from, writing $e^{\frac{1}{x(x+1)}} - 1 = \frac{1}{x(x+1)}$?

Comment: Yes, only I prefer to write it as $e^{1 \over{x(x+1)}} - 1  \over{x(x+1)}$$\to 1$.

Comment: right, but where does that come from?

Comment: Looks like L'hopital to me.

Comment: @Fred T. Added little explanation on end.

Comment: @A. Thomas Yerger. Formally here is used only $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1}{x}=1$, allowed by OP and substitution linked in answer.

Comment: In the course from which this problem came from, $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1}{x}=1$ follows from $\lim_{x\to0}(1+x)^{(1/x)}=e$, which, in turn, follows from the theorem that states that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+1/n)^n=e$, where $e$ is some number, $2<e<3$

Answer (score -2):

$$
L=\lim_{x\to\infty}x^2 \left( e^{1/x}-e^{1/(x+1)} \right).
$$
Let $t=1/x$, $\frac{1}{1+x}=t(1+t)^{-1}=t(1-t+t^2+O(t^3))$, then
$$L=\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{e^t-e^{t-t^2+O(t^3))}}{t^2}=\lim_{t\to 0} e^{t}\frac{1-e^{-t^2}}{t^2}=\lim_{t\to 0}e^t \frac{1-1+t^2+O(t^4)}{t^2}=1.$$

Comment: From the question: "without using the L'Hopital's rule or *Taylor series*".