# Limits containing infinity

Tags: limits

Let us consider the following limit:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \operatorname{cosec}^{-1}\frac{x}{x+7}.$$

According to my understanding both $x$ as well as $x+7$ tend toward $\infty$ as they can be cancelled to give us $1$ and the limit becomes $\pi$/$2$.

But in reality, the limit doesn't exist could someone explain why?

Comment: Actually it is not correct, @kipf - take a look at the graph and consider the function's domain.

Comment: begin by asking yourself the question: for which values of $u$ does $\csc^{-1} u$ exist?

Comment: $\csc(\theta) = \dfrac{1}{\sin(\theta)},~$ and $~\sin(\theta)~$ can not be larger than $~+1.$

Comment: You might  want to check values of $\operatorname{cosec}^{-1}\frac{x}{x+7}$ for some arguments first, say, $x = 1, \ 20, \ 7000, \ 10^{10},$ and see what they suggest... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function will need to be defined.

Note that the function
$
\operatorname{arccsc}(x)
$
has domain $(-\infty,-1] \cup [1,\infty)$.

However,
$$
x > 0 \implies x+7 > x \implies 0 < \frac{x}{x+7} < 1
$$
so $\operatorname{arccsc}(\frac{x}{x+7})$ is not defined as $x \to \infty$. It certainly doesn't have a limit as a result.

---

Your error is trying to use continuity and say
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \operatorname{arccsc}\left (\frac{x}{x+7} \right)
= 
\operatorname{arccsc}\left (\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x}{x+7} \right)
$$
This makes sense for functions continuous at and around a finite value $c$ as $x \to c$, but one has to be careful as $x \to \infty$. (For instance, "continuous at infinity" generally is a nonsensical notion.) As one sees [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4545377/bringing-limits-inside-functions-when-limits-go-to-infinity), that case can be quite a bit more complicated.